# PyQT QGraphicScene move item in background thread

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

Sorry for my bad english.
I need update graphic scene in background thread. I need that the thread move my rectangle on scene. But it doesn't work, when threads start, rectagle is hides on scene, and i can't see his move. Only if i move by mouse on scene other object, i can see how my rectangle move. But if i change color of rectangle in thread, it work fine. I want make simple client-server game, but i don't understand how move objects on scene from thread. I know, that QGraphics Scene is not thread-safe object, but how can i move objects in background, without timer or events?

```
class MyGraphicRect2(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.setPos(self.x, self.y)
        self.color = QColor('red')

        # self.setToolTip('Test')

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)


        s = Shadow()
        b = Blur()
        c = ColorChange()
        self.setGraphicsEffect(s)
        # self.setGraphicsEffect(c)

        # self.setGraphicsEffect(b)

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.color = QColor(color)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def paint(self, painter, options, widget):
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor('black')))
        painter.setBrush(self.color)
        painter.drawRect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)


class MoveThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self,object,scene,view):
        super().__init__()
        self.object=object
        self.scene=scene
        self.view=view
    def run(self):
        for i in range(1,10):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.object.moveBy(30,0)
            print(self.object.pos().x())
            #self.object.update()
            self.view.updateSceneRect(QRectF(0,0,800,800))


         #for color in ['green','white','black','magenta','yellow']:
         #   time.sleep(1)
         #   self.object.setColor(color)
         #   self.object.update()


class MyGraphicScene(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect=QRectF(0,0,800,800)
        self.Scene=QGraphicsScene(self.rect)
        self.View=QGraphicsView()
        self.View.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheNone)
        self.sceneConfig()

    def sceneConfig(self):
                         self.Scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor('yellow'),Qt.SolidPattern)))

    item=MyGraphicItem(30,30,100,100)
    self.item1=MyGraphicRect2(100,100,100,100)
    self.Scene.addItem(item)
    self.Scene.addItem(self.item1)
    line=QGraphicsLineItem(80,38,84,38)
    self.Scene.addItem(line)
    self.View.setScene(self.Scene)

def displayUI(self):
    print('Is scene active', self.Scene.isActive())
    self.setCentralWidget(self.View)
    self.th=MoveThread(self.item1,self.Scene,self.View)
    self.th.start()
    self.resize(1000,1000)
    self.show()


app=QApplication(sys.argv)

m=MyGraphicScene()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main thread runs the graphic part so in other threads should not be modified directly, this must be done by emitting a signal to the main thread and it is in its slot is where the graphic part is updated.

The following example creates a signal that is issued every second in the secondary thread, it connects to the `updatePosition` slot, and it is where the object moves.

```
class MyGraphicRect2(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.setPos(self.x, self.y)
        self.color = QColor('red')

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.color = QColor(color)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def paint(self, painter, options, widget):
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor('black')))
        painter.setBrush(self.color)
        painter.drawRect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)


class MoveThread(QThread):
    s = pyqtSignal(float, float)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def run(self):
        for i in range(1,10):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.s.emit(30,0)


class MyGraphicScene(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect=QRectF(0,0,800,800)
        self.Scene=QGraphicsScene(self.rect)
        self.View=QGraphicsView()
        self.View.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheNone)
        self.sceneConfig()
        self.displayUI()

    def sceneConfig(self):
        self.Scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor('yellow'),Qt.SolidPattern))

        self.item1=MyGraphicRect2(100,100,100,100)
        self.Scene.addItem(self.item1)
        line=QGraphicsLineItem(80,38,84,38)
        self.Scene.addItem(line)
        self.View.setScene(self.Scene)

    def updatePosition(self, x, y):
        self.item1.moveBy(x, y)

    def displayUI(self):
        print('Is scene active', self.Scene.isActive())
        self.setCentralWidget(self.View)
        self.th=MoveThread()
        self.th.s.connect(self.updatePosition)
        self.th.start()
        self.resize(1000,1000)
        self.show()

import sys
app=QApplication(sys.argv)

m=MyGraphicScene()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: WOW!! Its Works!!!! Thank YOU!!!!! Why did not such a thought come to my mind? After all, I have done before the exchange of signals between threads. Once again many thanks !!!!